# Nested for loops with i,j,k indices

Tags: c++

The output I am trying to get is:

```
 XX
 XX
X
 XX
 XX
X
 XX
X
X
 XX
 XX
X
 XX
X
X
 XX
X
X
X
 XX
 XX
X
 XX
X
X
 XX
X
X
X
 XX
X
X
X
X
```

my code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i, j, k;    

for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {cout<<" "<<"X"<<"X"<<'\n';
        for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
        cout<<"X"<<'\n';
            for (k=1; k<3; k++)
            cout<<" "<<"X"<<"X"<<'\n';  
    }

return 0;
}
```

my output for the code is:

```
 XX
X
 XX
 XX
X
X
 XX
 XX
 XX
X
X
X
 XX
 XX
 XX
X
X
X
X
 XX
 XX
```

I can only use 3 nested for loops with variables I , j, k . I am pretty sure it is a simple fix, but I have been staring at it and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Don't just stare... debug!

Comment: where do I find the debugger that goes step to step? I only know of the debug that looks for errors

Comment: Manual debugging. It's an art of programming.

Comment: Try something simpler first, like "0 01 012 0123 01234".

Comment: [OT]: you may replace `<< " " << "X" << "X"` by `<< " XX"`.

Comment: Manual debugging - breakpoints and see-through ;) also is this some sort of homework?

Comment: @user3479110: *Compilers* and *linkers* may spit out errors.  A *debugger* allows you to single step code and look at variables.

Comment: The code you posted is amazingly similar to the infamous "gotofail" bug. I'm quite sure it's not the code that produced your output.